# RecyclerView and SQLite: how do I run delete database record from Fragment?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

I have a LongClickListener in my RecyclerView's Adapter file that listens for LongClicks on CardViews in a RecyclerView list.  The Listener is linked with an interface to the RecyclerView Activity file.

Step 1 after the LongClick launches a DialogFragment for the user to confirm deletion of a CardView.  The dialog presents "Cancel" or "OK" choices.  "Cancel" just negates the DialogFragment.

Step 2 is where "OK" was selected and the delete code in the DatabaseHelper file will remove the CardView data from the SQLite database.

Step 3 will be an intent to run the RecyclerView Activity again so that the RecyclerView list refreshes and shows the updated list (with the previous CardView removed since the data was deleted in the database).

I am good with Step 1 as a LongClick on any CardView is launches the DialogFragment as expected.  I am stuck on Step 2 in the Fragment line "dbHelper.deletefromDB(UserData userdata);".  Android Studio warning message is "Cannot resolve symbol 'userdata'".  What am I missing here?  Below shows the various files in question.

```
ListActivity file:
...
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    dbList = dbHelper.getAllDataFromDB();
    ...
    ListAdapter mAdapter;        
    mAdapter = new ListAdapter(this, dbList);        
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    mAdapter.setonItemClickListener(new ListAdapter.ClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemLongClick(int position, View view) {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            DeleteCardViewFragment delCardViewDialog = new DeleteCardViewFragment();
            delCardViewDialog.show(fm, "delcardview dialog");
        }
    });

DatabaseHelper file:
public class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    ...
    public void deletefromDB(UserData userData) {        
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.beginTransaction();
    db.delete(DBContract.DBEntry.TABLE_NAME_USERINPUTS, DBContract.DBEntry.COLUMN_NAME_ID + " = ?",
        new String[]{String.valueOf(userData.getId())});
    db.setTransactionSuccessful();
    db.endTransaction();
    if(db.isOpen())
        db.close();
 }    
}

DeleteCardViewFragment file:
public class DeleteCardViewFragment extends DialogFragment {

DatabaseHelper dbHelper;

public DeleteCardViewFragment() {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.delcardview_layout, container, false);
    getDialog().setTitle("Delete card");
    dbHelper = new DatabaseHelper(getActivity());

    Button btnCancel = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnCancel);
    btnCancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getDialog().cancel();
        }
    });

    Button btnOK = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.btnOK);
    btnOK.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dbHelper.deletefromDB(UserData userdata);                
            dismiss();

        }
    });    
    ...
 }
}
```

Comment: Is UserData something you defined? Have you tried just using a string instead?

Comment: UserData userdata is set up as the cursor in the DatabaseHelper file to hold all of the user input data.